Training a neural network on two dataset simultaneously
I have my neural network model and want to train it at the same time on 2 datasets that share the same structure. What I have done so far does not work.
This is my code
data1 = {0. -> {0., 1.}, 0.2 -> {0.2, 1.3313}, 0.4 -> {0.4, 1.12215}, 
   0.6 -> {0.6, 1.74427}, 0.8 -> {0.8, 2.10747}, 1. -> {1., 2.08546}};

data2 = {0. -> {0., 1.1}, 0.2 -> {0.2, 1.223}, 0.4 -> {0.4, 1.14}, 
   0.6 -> {0.6, 1.65}, 0.8 -> {0.8, 2.13}, 1. -> {1., 2.31}};


deep = NetChain[{100, LinearLayer[100], Tanh, 2}]; wGraph = 
 NetGraph[<|"net" -> deep, "loss" -> MeanSquaredLossLayer[], 
   "times" -> ThreadingLayer[Times]|>, {"net" -> 
    "loss", {NetPort["Weight"], "loss"} -> 
    "times" -> NetPort["WeightedLoss"]}];
dataset := <|"Input" -> Thread[{data1[[All, 1]], data2[[All, 1]]}], 
   "Target" -> Thread[{data1[[All, 2]], data2[[All, 2]]}], 
   "Weight" -> Table[1, Length[data1]]|>;

final = With[{result = 
    NetTrain[wGraph, dataset, LossFunction -> "WeightedLoss", 
     MaxTrainingRounds -> 5000, BatchSize -> 200]}, 
  final = NetExtract[result, "net"]]

The following evaluation fails:
final[{0.2}]

Any suggestion of changes (however obvious?)

It appears the dimensionality of your dataset is inconsistent for the network inputs.
"Input" -> {6,2,2}
"Target" -> {6,2}
"Weight" -> {6}
"Input" should be a list of length 2 vectors.  The training will require that each dataset component also will need to have the same length for the training to proceed.
